# Row Validating in DataGridView with data from Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, validation, stored-procedures, datagridview

In DataGridView I have two ComboBox columns:

> ```
> private string controlFrom= "cmbMachineAndOpIDFrom";
> private string controlTo = "cmbMachineAndOpIDTo";
> ```

I want to check those two-columns combination for duplicates. If duplicate exists or null the record must be cancelled with message for the user. I try to use RowValidating event for that:

```
    private void dgvTransfers_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        string columName = dgvTransfers.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
        e.Cancel = IsDuplicateExists(columName);
    }
```

The code of IsDuplicateExist:

```
    private bool IsDuplicateExists(string colName)
    {
        bool res = false;
        int existingRowID = 0;

        if (colName.Equals(controlFrom) || colName.Equals(controlTo))
        {
            int cmbFrom = Convert.ToInt32(Helper.GetSelectedRowValueInDGV(dgvTransfers, controlFrom));
            int cmbTo = Convert.ToInt32(Helper.GetSelectedRowValueInDGV(dgvTransfers, controlTo));

            if (cmbFrom == 0 || cmbTo == 0)
            {
                res = true;
            }
            //Check for duplicates
            existingRowID = Helper.GetDuplicatedRowIndex(cmbFrom, cmbTo, dgvTransfers, controlFrom, controlTo);

            if (existingRowID > 0)
            {
                //Already exists
                GoToDublicatedRecord(existingRowID, dgvTransfers);
                res = true;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

I always get 0 value for `cmbFrom` and `cmbTo` using method `GetSelectedRowValueInDGV`:

```
    public static string GetSelectedRowValueInDGV(DataGridView dgvName, string columnName)
    {
        string res = "0";

        if (dgvName.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            var vl = dgvName.SelectedRows[0].Cells[columnName].Value;
            if (vl.ToString()!=string.Empty && vl != null && vl != DBNull.Value)
            {
                res = dgvName.SelectedRows[0].Cells[columnName].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

So first question is why I do not get selected cell value?

Here comes the second part of problem. Since both values are zeroes I get `e.Cancel = true`. Here I expect editing to be cancelled but instead I get error

> 'Operation did not succeed because the program cannot commit or quit a
> cell value change.'

at row `dgvName.DataSource = dt;` in `CellValueChanged` event where `GetDataForGridView` is called to get data from SQL SP:

```
        public static bool GetDataForGridView(DataGridView dgvName, string storedProcedureName, params SqlParameter[] arrParam)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        bool result;

        // Open the connection 
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
        {
            try
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                // Define the command 
                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd.CommandText = storedProcedureName;

                    // Handle the parameters 
                    if (arrParam != null)
                    {
                        foreach (SqlParameter param in arrParam)
                        {
                            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                        }
                    }

                    // Define the data adapter and fill the dataset 
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                result = false;
            }

            dgvName.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dgvName.DataSource = dt;


            sqlConn.Close();

        }
        return result;
    }
```

**UPDATED**

Here is how both Comboboxes are populated:

```
    private void FrmTransfers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Helper.GetDataForGridView(dgvTransfers, "pp_sp_Transfers", null);

        PopCombo(cmbMachineAndOpIDFrom, "MachineAndOpID",0,0);
        PopCombo(cmbMachineAndOpIDTo, "MachineAndOpID",0,0);
    }
    
    private void PopCombo(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo, string valMember, int parValue1, int parValue2)
    {
        DataTable dtMO = Helper.ExecuteDataTable("pp_sp_MachineAndOp",
                                       new SqlParameter("@MachineAndOpID", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = parValue1 },
                                       new SqlParameter("@Seq", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = parValue2 });

        //Add field to be displayed
        dtMO.Columns.Add("ToShow", typeof(string), "'Seq: ' + Seq  + '    ID: ' + MachineAndOpID + ' (' + OperationID + ') ' + Operation + ' + ' + Machine");

        // bind data table into combo box.
        combo.DataSource = dtMO;
        combo.DisplayMember = "ToShow";
        combo.ValueMember = valMember;
    }
```

Comment: You do not say or show “how” each combo box column in the grid is set up. Do both columns contain the same data? How is the data bound to the combo boxes items list? You ask… _”So first question is why I do not get selected cell value?”_ … ? … I do not see in the code where the combo box cells/columns items list is being populated, so it is unknown “what” those values may be.

Comment: The `GetSelectedRowValueInDGV` method looks like it “should” get the cells value, even though the `if` conditions look backwards. Checking if `vl.ToString()` is empty BEFORE checking if `vl` is `null` is obviously the cart before the horse.

Comment: I am guessing it may be more user friendly, if the code “filtered” out the “already” selected item when the user selects the second combo box. Example if both combo box values are “empty” and the user selects a value in the first or second combo box, then, when the user selects the other combo box on the same row, then the code will look to see “which” value is selected in the other combo box, then remove “that” item from “this” combo boxes list of items. This way the user will NOT be able to select duplicate values. Just a thought.

Comment: @JohnG I have updated code with combo box population part. BTW If I comment 'Row Validating' code I do not get any error. As suggested I also have tried approach to synchronize combo boxes by filtering second combo according to value in first combo. It resulted into random empty second combo cells in other records.

Comment: Unless you want to pursue your current path to validate this, I can only ask, “how” you previously attempted to “filter” the combo boxes. In my tests, subscribing the grids `EditingColtrolShowing` event made filtering the individual combo boxes relatively easy. Can you elaborate on what you previously tried when “filtering” the combo boxes and what the problems were? What events did you use and how did you filter the data?

Comment: I am just saying that your current code is missing to much and I am betting there is more going on than you are currently revealing. So you should decide “How” you want to deal with this “duplication” of the values. There are numerous ways to do this and your current approach will certainly work if implemented correctly. Pick your poison, I can show an example using `DataTable`s and `DataViews` to filter each individual combo box cell so it is not possible to select “duplicate” values.

Comment: My approach was to create Stored Procedure with parameters and re-bind data using `SqlDataAdater`. Now I know it is bad approach but I did not find the way how to do filter only on current row. I prefer to return to sync combo boxes but maybe I need to open new question for that.

Comment: I have rewritten my code using filter on DataView but now faced with new issues. Here is new question:  [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68484367/filter-values-in-combo-box-a-based-on-selected-value-in-combo-box-b-in-datagridv